# Are Pappus Theorems generalized?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, euclidean-geometry

[Pappus' Centroid Theorems](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html) provide a slick way of computing the center of mass for plane curves and plane areas.

The first theorem states that the surface area $A$ of a surface of revolution generated by rotating a plane curve $\Gamma$ about an axis external to $\Gamma$ and on the same plane is equal to the product of the arc length $s$ of $\Gamma$ and the distance $d$ traveled by its geometric centroid.$$A=sd$$

The second theorem states that the volume $V$ of a solid of revolution generated by rotating a plane figure F about an external axis is equal to the product of the area $A$ of F and the distance $d$ traveled by its geometric centroid. $$V=ad$$

In both theorems, $d=2 \pi y_{c}$, where $y_{c}$ is the required centroid. When we were taught in class the techniques of evaluation of the centroids of three dimensional figures via integration, I remember that the evaluation of the centroid of the hollow hemisphere was particularly difficult for me. So I ask if there are Pappus-like theorems which one could apply for three dimensional bodies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a neat way of finding the centroid of surfaces/volumes of revolution. Suppose you have a planar figure $\Gamma$ and an axis $\ell$ in the plane that is disjoint from $\Gamma$. Now suppose that the centroid of $\Gamma$ projects on $\ell$ as $O$, and that it's distance from $\ell$ is $r$. Suppose we rotate $\Gamma$ around $\ell$ with an angle of $\alpha$, and call the resulting body $\Gamma(\alpha)$.

To find the centroid of $\Gamma(\alpha)$, $G_{\alpha}$, it is enough to measure it's distance from $O$, since $OG_{\alpha}\perp \ell$ and $G_{\alpha}$ is on the dihedral bisector of the angle of revolution. Let's denote $|OG_{\alpha}|$ by $f(\alpha)$, so that by cutting $\Gamma(\alpha)$ into two $\Gamma (\alpha/2)$'s, and using Archimedes lemma that the centroid of the union of two objects is in the line joining the separate centroids, we get the functional equation $$f(\alpha)=f(\alpha/2)\cos (\alpha/4)$$ with initial condition $f(0)=r$, so that by continuity the solution is $f(\alpha)=2r\frac{\sin (\alpha/2)}{\alpha}$. This method takes care of all examples like the hollow hemisphere etc.

Answer (score 5):

**Note**: This is a generalization in a different direction from what the question asked for (these references generalize in terms of finding volumes, but Koundinya Vajjha wanted a generalization in terms of finding the centroid).  The higher dimensional version by Gray and Miquel linked to below might yield this, but I haven't read their paper yet.

A quick google search yielded the following reference: ["Generalizations of the Theorems of Pappus" by A. W. Goodman and Gary Goodman](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2316426).

They show that the second theorem you stated has a generalization when the circle that the centroid of F travels on is replaced with any sufficiently smooth simple closed space curve whose curvature never vanishes, however, the first theorem does not generalize easily.

I had to share Figure 1 from the paper - you can apparently compute the volume of the solid you get when you transport the "face" $\mathcal{D}$ bounded by $\mathcal{C}_P$ around the curve $\mathcal{C}_S$.  [$\mathcal{C}_S$ is not actually knotted, but the authors state that "... the curve $\mathcal{C}_S$ may even have knots in it, as we have tried to indicate in Figure 1".]

[image: Figure 1 from Goodman and Goodman]

Now, for even more generalizations, you can look at [the papers on google scholar that cite this](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=13901652430294794554&as_sdt=20000005&sciodt=0,21&hl=en):

There's [a paper of Alfred Gray and Vicente Miquel](http://www.springerlink.com/content/l1315v831g737660) that discusses volumes of similar constructions in space forms.  Their motivation was to try to better understand [Weyl's famous tube formula](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/03/intrinsic_volumes_for_riemanni.html).  M. Carmen Domingo-Juan, Ximo Gual and Vicente Miquel have since written [several](http://www.springerlink.com/content/ah247j782m402513/) [more](http://www.springerlink.com/content/t4345j4m12827411/) [papers](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-belgian-mathematical-society-simon-stevin/volume-13/issue-1/Pappus-Guldin-theorems-for-weighted-motions/10.36045/bbms/1148059338.full) on the subject.

Comment: The links to `springerlink.com` are broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshots saved on the Wayback Machine.